# Export Rundeck execution history

Tags: rundeck

I would like to export the full execution history under the "Activity" tab of a rundeck project (preferably in a delimited format such as csv). I have checked the rd-queue cli interface, but that only shows the currently running jobs.

Is there a way to export all of the jobs as seen under the activity tab? In other words, I'm looking for a list with the name of each job, its start time and duration and the user who ran the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find an export feature, but you can find the job executions stored in files on the server.  The directory is configurable within the log4j.properties file.

By default, these files are in the /var/log/rundeck/ directory.